# How do I pass a JSON object as well as a simple string to a controller via an AJAX call?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api

Here's my route:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "InsertOrUpdateDirector", routeTemplate: "api/awards/directors", defaults: new
    {
       controller = "Awards", action = "InsertDirector"
    });
```

Here's the controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public void InsertOrUpdateDirector(Director director, string operation)
{
   string query = null;

   myConnection.Open();
   if (operation == "I")
   {
     query = "INSERT INTO...";
   }
   else if (operation == "U")
   {
     query = "UPDATE...";
   }
   var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   myConnection.Close();
}
```

If I send a JSON object to the above, it works.

Now I need to be able to pass the JSON object as well as a string parameter.

Here's the AJAX call passing only the JSON object:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/x/api/awards/directors",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: directorData 
     }).done(function () {
         detailRow.find(".directorsOrRecipients").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
     });
```

My question is, how do I pass the JSON object as well as the string "I" to the controller in this scenario?

`directorData` is a JSON object, by the way.

Comment: You need to create a JSON objet with a `director` property and an `operation` property. The former would contain your directorData and the latter the string you wish to pass.

Comment: This was actually the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a JSON object with a director property and an operation property. The former would contain your directorData and the latter the string you wish to pass.

Comment: This was the simplest solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One quick approach would be to just add it to the URL as a query string parameter:

```
url: "http://localhost/x/api/awards/directors?operation=I"
```

or, if you have a variable for it:

```
url: "http://localhost/x/api/awards/directors?operation=" + operationValue
```

Another option would be to add the "operation" value to the JSON object itself.  I don't know what a `Director` is in your code, but for the sake of argument let's say it's this:

```
{
    "ID" : 1,
    "Name" : "John"
}
```

Then you could add another value to that JSON object:

```
{
    "ID" : 1,
    "Name" : "John",
    "operation" : "I"
}
```

This won't confuse the model binding for the server-side action method parameters.  The JSON object doesn't need to *exactly* line up with one of the models.  The model binding is going to make a best effort to determine the action method parameter values based on all of the values being posted to the action.  So in the above JSON object it will know that "ID" and "Name" make up a `Director` object, and that "operation" is the `string` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the route so that it can handle the operation:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "InsertOrUpdateDirector",
    routeTemplate: "api/awards/directors/{operation}",
    defaults: new
       {
           controller = "Awards",
           action = "InsertDirector",
           operation = UrlParameter.Optional
       });
```

Then when you call it, format the URL appropriately:

```
url: "/Awards/directors/someoper",
```

This works on regular MVC (I don't have WebAPI on this machine, but I would expect it would work there too).

Personally, I'd avoid mixing the `operation` in with the regular model. It may work, but it might get confusing later.